# How to write these queries in spring repository abstraction format

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, spring-boot, findandmodify

1.
Consider I have a class which has a Map

```
public class MobileToken
{

    @Id
    private String                    _id;

    @Indexed
    private String                    username;
    private String                    applicationId;
    private Map<String, String> tokens;
}
```

How can I Get/Delete a single token from the Map of tokens using its key? The operation will result in partial update of the document.

2.
In a class I want to use $set operation or findAndModify like Query.
Considering above class, I wanna find all records with a given sets of username and wanna update all record's applicationId by some value "abc".

Is there any convention to achieve both these scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, I would use spring data and QueryDSL integration. QueryDSL would create its meta model (`QModels`) for each of your documents annotated with `@Document` and you can use them to create flexible queries. In you case you would have a meta model, say, `QMobileToken`.

> 2. In a class I want to use $set operation or findAndModify like Query. Considering above class, I wanna find all records with a given
>      sets of username and wanna update all record's applicationId by some
>      value "abc".

If you're using java 8, you could add `default` method in your `MobileTokenRepository`, like this:

```
public interface MobileTokenRepository extends MongoRepository<MobileToken, String>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MobileToken> {
    QMobileToken token = MobileToken.mobileToken;
     ...
    default Iterable<MobileToken> findByUsernames(Collection<String> usernames) {
        return findAll(token.username.in(usernmaes));
    }
}
```

Use this `findByUsernames` method and iterate each `MobileToken`, change each accordingly and use `save` method to save your changes to mongo.

To enable this integration, add these dependencies to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and add `apt-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>src/main/generated</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

In order to tell QueryDSL to create its required meta models, compile by `mvn clean compile` (Do this every time you add a new document or change an existing one)